# Creating ipa from XCode 7.x and submit to AppStore is supported for iOS 10?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios10, appstore-approval

Our app already live in AppStore. Now i am going to take ipa from Xcode 7 with iOS 7.0 greater choosen. Also ll upload this binary from Application loader not from XCode. Xcode 7.3 has iOS 9 sdk. I know to run this app in device i need to go for Xcode 8.

Will this binary support iOS 10 devices?

OR I need to create ipa in Xcode 8.0?

Comment: There's nothing that will automatically stop it from running.  If you haven't tested on iOS 10, you don't know how well it will run or if there's some bug that only show up there...but, in theory, it's OK.

Comment: why not surely support

Comment: Thanks for the update, ok i ll check it now for my build

Answer (score 0):

Sure, i've uploaded an ipa file (built with xCode 7.3) to ItunesConnect and it's currently online and available for iOS 10 devices. You could install manually iOS 10 simulators to test your app on iOS 10 using xCode 7.x

Comment: Thanks for the update, ok i ll check it now for my build.